# Outlook web add-in (Office 1906) and Windows 10 build 1903 - how to clear cache?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

We need to clear the (embedded) browser cache when we manually install a new version of our add-in. Before the July 2019 update of Office we just could remove the Internet Explorer 11 cache and so was our add-in updated.

But this does not work for the embedded Edge version. So how do I clear the temporary cache?

- Already tried removing it with command rmdir %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\ /s /q

  - Removing the cache using the experimental Edge Devtools does work, but this is only suiteable for developers
  - Removing IE cache also didn't work

Comment: Currently, using the devtools to clear the cache is the only way to do this. For debugging purposes you could also add a "no-cache" header to your files, with the caveat that your files will no longer be cached for perf purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing a new version, can you version the folder where the files are being served from? - or if served from Windows Server, hack the case of the URL in the manifest, as Windows is not case sensitive (but the browser is).

Also, Outlook caches the resources listed in the manifest (images, etc.) separately, and it is necessary to change the URL of those if they are updated -- or you would also have to clear Outlook's cache on the computer.